# Accessing own calendar (Not user's) on actions on google, for google assistant

Tags: node.js, jwt, actions-on-google

I am trying to create an action that reads information from my own calendar to any user that asks for it through Google Assistant.

Please note that I do not want every user to be able to access their respective calendar details. But I want them to be able to access my calendar details via the action.

I tried this based on what I found [here](http://isd-soft.com/nl/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/)

This is what I was trying, but it never worked. Does anyone of you have any idea why?

```
... //other declarations and stuff

let Assistant = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiAssistant;

... //rest of the code


//Specific action corresponding to the read Calendar intent.

function readCalendarAction (assistant) {


function finalResponse(response){

assistant.ask(response); //final response from fullfillment

}

let google = require('googleapis');
let privatekey = require("./mynewpk.json");

// configure a JWT auth client
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
       privatekey.client_email,
       null,
       privatekey.private_key,
       ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);
//authenticate request
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
 if (err) {
   //console.log(err);
   var response = 'This one is an error';
   finalResponse(response);

   return;
 } else {
   //console.log("Successfully connected!");
   //var response = 'this is the newer answer';
   //finalResponse(response);
 }
});

//Google Calendar API
let calendar = google.calendar('v3');
calendar.events.list({
   auth: jwtClient,
   calendarId: 'primary'
}, function (err, response) {
   if (err) {
       console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
       return;
   }
   var events = response.items;
   var response = events[0].summary;
   finalResponse(response);

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "never worked"? What do the logs show? What is getting sent to the assistant? Does the assistant show anything? How are you triggering it? Can you show screen shots from the simulator?

Comment: (And what version of the library are you using?)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
About 'never worked':
Well, in fact, it works perfectly when I try the same on my local machine with npm. (googleapis installed)

I will share the exact error responses from 'Dialogflow' later today.
From what I remember, the fulfilment response was empty.

Comment: Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error

This is the error that I'm getting on Dialogflow

Comment: Which call is giving you that error?

Comment: Sorry that I am not able to provide such detailed information. As my name indicates, I'm still figuring out this thing.

To provide you with enough context, I am using https://dialogflow.com to build the basic agent interaction.

I am using a webhook for fulfillment.

The code for fulfillment is on Heroku. (a part of which I have shown here)

I am not sure if this is happening because of some kind of restriction from Actions on google.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it is a restriction from Acitons on Google. Do you have Heroku logs that are reporting what is going on? Without knowing where in your code (or where, exactly, in Dialogflow the error is shown to you) the Error 500 is coming from, it is difficult to diagnose, and that's what I'm trying to help you track down.